# How do I input text onClick into a set of divs I created

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

It populates all the divs at once instead of adding the texts one box at a time. What I want to do is to add an alphabet to each box. How do i achieve this?

```
 <div id="alphabet"></div>

 <div id="choice" class="choice">
    <div class="chi" id="chi">b</div>
    <div class="chi" id="chi">s</div>
    <div class="chi" id="chi">a</div>
    <div class="chi" id="chi">v</div>
    <div class="chi" id="chi">y</div>
    <div class="chi" id="chi">c</div>

const alphabet = document.getElementById('alphabet')
const input = document.getElementById('input')
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn')

let cc = 4;
for (let i = 0; i < cc; i++) {
  let tt = document.createElement('div')
tt.classList.add('newie')
alphabet.append(tt);

choice.addEventListener('click', populateDivs)
function populateDivs(e){
    let clickedAlphabet = e.target.innerText;
          tt.innerHTML = clickedAlphabet;

}
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with querySelectorAll.

```
const allDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".chi");

allDivs.forEach(function(element) {
   // Whatever you want to happen.
});
```

Comment: just added the code

Comment: @MorzookBiobaku I mean you still need to add the part that you want, I just provided the method how to. Im not sure what you want so I didnt write more. What my code does, is that it puts ALL your divs with class of chi, as an array inside "allDivs". Then it targets one at the time as element parameter within the function. 

So where it says // Whatever you want to happen.

You can do what you want with each of the divs by referring to them as "element".

So if you type element.textContent = "Hello there".

Every single div with the class of ".chi" will get "Hello there" inside.

Comment: thanks for your response. I am quite new to this and it is confusing. i have used loops to create a set of four divs that I call boxes. I also created the div choice that holds six other divs 'chi' . each chi has holds an alphabet and i want to be able to click on each alphabet and append the value into one of the boxes i created. When i click it presently, all the boxes gets updated with the alphabet clicked. i only want just one box to be filled with each alphabet clicked. I hope you get it now

Comment: Filip#4878 is my discord. This will be much easier if you are open for a call. You can add me, we can share the screens, I can help you fix your problem but most importantly, we can take it few steps back. You have some habits that we need to get rid of like multiple of the same ids. And I can perhaps answer some more questions you might have?

Comment: Sidenote: If you are going to add me, must be capital "F", there is another person with small "f".